# Getting Exception While Downloading pdf From Link in Android

Tags: java, android, pdf

While Downloading pdf from link m getting error and its directly going to the catch and exception has been caught there therefore i have implemented permission into the manifest file . still m getting exception at file download time .
here is my code

```
TextView tv_loading;
String dest_file_path = "test.pdf";
int downloadedSize = 0, totalsize;
String download_file_url = "http://ilabs.uw.edu/sites/default/files/sample_0.pdf";
float per = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv_loading = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv_loading);
    tv_loading.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv_loading.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    downloadAndOpenPDF();
}

void downloadAndOpenPDF() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(downloadFile(download_file_url));
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                tv_loading
                        .setError("PDF Reader application is not installed in your device");
            }
        }
    }).start();

}

File downloadFile(String dwnload_file_path) {
    File file = null;
    try {

        URL url = new URL(dwnload_file_path);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        // connect
        urlConnection.connect();

        // set the path where we want to save the file
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // create a new file, to save the downloaded file
        file = new File(SDCardRoot, dest_file_path);

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // Stream used for reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        // this is the total size of the file which we are
        // downloading
        totalsize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        setText("Starting PDF download...");

        // create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];  
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            per = ((float) downloadedSize / totalsize) * 100;
            setText("Total PDF File size  : "
                    + (totalsize / 1024)
                    + " KB\n\nDownloading PDF " + (int) per
                    + "% complete");
        }
        // close the output stream when complete //
        fileOutput.close();
        setText("Download Complete. Open PDF Application installed in the device.");

    } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
        setTextError("Some error occured. Press back and try again.",
                Color.RED);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        setTextError("Some error occured. Press back and try again.",
                Color.RED);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        setTextError(
                "Failed to download image. Please check your internet connection.",
                Color.RED);
    }
    return file;
}

void setTextError(final String message, final int color) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tv_loading.setTextColor(color);
            tv_loading.setText(message);
        }
    });

}

void setText(final String txt) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tv_loading.setText(txt);
        }
    });

}
```

thanks For help in Advance

Comment: What is the actual exception message you receive?

Comment: Please put your exception

Comment: There are many things you can ask from the [URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) after connecting. `setDoOutput` is not needed. A bit info would be nice. The returned getContentLengthLong() might be -1L when not present. You might need to fake a Mozilla browser by setting header fields.

Comment: its Getting IOException

Comment: Please provide the full exception stack trace. Just saying `IOException` is thrown does not help, since network I/O has a plethora of reasons as to why throw an `IOException`.